# how to paste excel formula correctly

Tags: excel, excel-formula

- I made cell A1 equal 1.39139
- Made cell B1 equal 1.40596
- Made cell C1 a formula `=(A1-B1)*10000`
- Copied cell C1 and pasted it by value into cell D1
- In cell E1 I wrote manually the real result of the calculation, which is -145.7 (you can try using a calculator).

[image]

- In cell F1 I made an if statement to compare the results of E1 and F1: `=IF(E1=D1,"equal","not equal")`
- The result is "not equal".

[image]

**I want to know how to copy and paste a formula and make sure its pasted result will be exactly the same. keep in mind that I don't want to use `=round()` formula because I need a solution for many numbers, and I can't use `round()` for each cell with different number of digits.

Comment: This is likely due to the Floating-point precision that Excel uses.  It is often known to cause issues like what you've described.  Here are a few links with information about the problem and how to address it: [link](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/), [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/78113/floating-point-arithmetic-may-give-inaccurate-results-in-excel), and [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214118/how-to-correct-rounding-errors-in-floating-point-arithmetic).

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, this is because of Excel's floating point precision.

You are correct that `(1.39139-1.40596)*10000` is equal to `-145.7`. However, I tried typing this into Excel to see what it actually produced and I found the following. If you highlight your cell `C1` and press <kbd>F9</kbd> on the keyboard you will see that Excel actually computes this value as `-145.700000000002`.

I know you said you don't want to use `ROUND` but, aside from avoiding floating point numbers altogether (i.e. only using integers), I think `ROUND` is your only option.

I suggest that you determine what is the maximum number of digits after the decimal you will ever need in your sheet, and incorporate `ROUND(<number>,<max digits>)` into all formulas as necessary.

i.e. instead of using `=(A1-B1)*10000`, you should type `=ROUND((A1-B1)*10000,5)` (for example to round to 5 digits) which would return the value of **exactly** `-145.7`. I hope this helps, or if nothing else, I hope this at least shed light on what is causing this.